# Getting this error when tried to install using pip install anymail

Tags: python, django, django-anymail

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement anymail (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for anymail

Can anyone help me with this

Comment: what pip cmd are you using to install that package?

Answer (score 2):

```
pip install django-anymail
```

Some Python packages have a different name with which to install them

Comment: (Anymail maintainer here) This is the correct answer. See [Anymail installation docs](https://anymail.dev/en/stable/installation/) for additional info.

Answer (score 0):

try upgrading your pip `pip install --upgrade pip`

note: you may need to check your other packages after the upgrade